# Async throw error: "End of statement expected"

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing a outlook addin with VSTO VB and want to create a async sub.
This is the following code:

```
Public Async Sub TestAsync()
    Msgbox("test")
End Sub
```

But after the Async, the compiler says: "End of statement expected".

I also tried to make a function instead, but with no success(same error):

```
Public Async Function TestAsync() As Task
    Msgbox("test")
End Function
```

What I'm missing with the async declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Async` keyword was added to [VB.NET version 11.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#2012_.28VB_11.0.29), which was released along side [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) and [.NET Framework 4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.5).  The first version of Visual Studio Tools for Office which supported .NET 4.5 was [VSTO version 4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office).  It was included in the [Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/03/06/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-now-available.aspx).

Comment: Ok so I use .NET 4.0.. is there any similar to async in older versions??

Comment: No.  `Async` was completely new in 4.5.  Prior to TAP (which makes use of `Async` and `Await`), the two recommended patterns for asynchronous programming were APM and EAP. See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a comparision of the three patterns.  Both APM and EAP were available prior to 4.5.  With 4.0, APM became a bit easier because of the addition of the `Task` class.